# Partial Fraction Decomposition Clarification

Tags: partial-fractions

I'm just looking for some overall clarification for the following cases. Now, to the extent of my knowledge, the following examples of partial fractions would be split up in the following way:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2+3x-4}&=\frac{1}{\left(x+4\right)\left(x-1\right)}=\frac{A}{x+4}+\frac{B}{x-1},\tag{1}\\
\frac{1}{x^3+x^2}&=\frac{1}{x^2\left(x+1\right)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x+1},\tag{2}\\
\frac{1}{x^2\left(x+1\right)^3}&=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{D}{\left(x+1\right)^2}+\frac{E}{\left(x+1\right)^3},\tag{3}\\
\frac{1}{x^2\left(x^2+x+1\right)}&=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+x+1},\tag{4}\\
\frac{1}{x^2\left(x^3+x^2+x+1\right)^2}&=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{Cx^2+Dx+E}{x^3+x^2+x+1}+\frac{Fx^2+Gx+H}{\left(x^3+x^2+x+1\right)^2},\tag{5}
\end{align}
have I made a mistake anywhere?

---

EDIT: I should have factored $\left(5\right)$ further to get
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2\left(\left(x+1\right)\left(x^2+1\right)\right)^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: The cubic (last problem) factors.

Comment: $x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = (x + 1)(x^2 + 1)$

Comment: @AndréNicolas My bad, I meant for it to not be factorable...

Comment: Cubics are all in principle factorable over the reals.

Comment: @AndréNicolas If I did not factor them, however, would (5) still be correct or incorrect?

Comment: Correct. But usually not adequate for the subsequent integration.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Okay :) I understand that as well, I was just looking to make sure I had split them up correctly based on the "basic" principles, and I was not considering them as integrands. Surely, however, (5) and some others, as you have said, would not make things much easier if I were to do that for integrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x^3+x^2+x+1 = x^2(x+1) + 1(x+1) = (x^2+1)(x+1)
$$
So
$$
\frac{\cdots\cdots\cdots}{x^3+x^2+x+1} = \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+1} + \frac{E}{x+1}.
$$